# Trying to check if the user has input the correct text c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the user input a sentence into an input field and then I need to check whether the user has input the correct sentence or not, if they input correctly I want to be able to change the scene (I have used a Debug.Log as a placeholder).

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CheckInput : MonoBehaviour {

public InputField WordInput;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
public void CheckforWords () {
    if (WordInput.text == "please") 
    {
        Debug.Log("Youre a Lad");   
    } 
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Nope");
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Hello Myoungs, and welcome to the site. We generally try to keep questions and answers to-the-point around here, so I trimmed yours down a bit.  Feel free to edit it if you aren't happy with the changes.

Comment: Also, when you post something like this, it really helps if you tell us what you want to happen AS WELL as what is actually happening. I can't see from this code what is calling the "CheckForWords" method.

Comment: Just put CheckWords() into void Update()

Answer (score 0):

To load a level programmatically in Unity3D:

```
Application.LoadLevel (Destination);
```

You'll need to make sure your scene is added to the level collection otherwise you'll run into a null reference.

**Reference:** https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 event of Inputfield : onEndEdit and onValueChange

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onEndEdit.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChange.html

You can edit in inspector and use SceneManager.LoadScene

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html